# fails to restore from checkpoint file and train in the distributed machines

Tags: tensorflow

I run the mnist conv code and save the model as "test_model1-1" and test_model1-1.meta:

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import input_data

batch_size = 128
test_size = 256


def save(sess, path, pb_name, as_text):
    # 从checkpoint保存variables的信息
   if as_text:
       tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, path, pb_name,True)
   else:
       tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, path, pb_name, False)
def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01))


def model(X, w, w2, w3, w4, w_o, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden):
    # define a constant 255
    scale = tf.constant(255,tf.float32)
    X = tf.mul(X,scale)
    print np.max(X)
    l1a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(X, w,                       # l1a shape=(?, 28, 28, 32)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l1 = tf.nn.max_pool(l1a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l1 shape=(?, 14, 14, 32)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l1 = tf.nn.dropout(l1, p_keep_conv)

    l2a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(l1, w2,                     # l2a shape=(?, 14, 14, 64)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l2 = tf.nn.max_pool(l2a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l2 shape=(?, 7, 7, 64)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l2 = tf.nn.dropout(l2, p_keep_conv)

    l3a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(l2, w3,                     # l3a shape=(?, 7, 7, 128)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l3 = tf.nn.max_pool(l3a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l3 shape=(?, 4, 4, 128)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l3 = tf.reshape(l3, [-1, w4.get_shape().as_list()[0]])    # reshape to (?, 2048)
    l3 = tf.nn.dropout(l3, p_keep_conv)

    l4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(l3, w4))
    l4 = tf.nn.dropout(l4, p_keep_hidden)

    pyx = tf.matmul(l4, w_o)
    return pyx

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
trX, trY, teX, teY = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels, mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels
trX = trX.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)  # 28x28x1 input img
teX = teX.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)  # 28x28x1 input img
print np.max(trX)
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 28, 28, 1], name='input_X')
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10], name='input_Y')

w = init_weights([3, 3, 1, 32])       # 3x3x1 conv, 32 outputs
w2 = init_weights([3, 3, 32, 64])     # 3x3x32 conv, 64 outputs
w3 = init_weights([3, 3, 64, 128])    # 3x3x32 conv, 128 outputs
w4 = init_weights([128 * 4 * 4, 625]) # FC 128 * 4 * 4 inputs, 625 outputs
w_o = init_weights([625, 10])         # FC 625 inputs, 10 outputs (labels)

p_keep_conv = tf.placeholder("float", name = 'p_keep_conv')
p_keep_hidden = tf.placeholder("float", name = 'p_keep_hidden')
py_x = model(X, w, w2, w3, w4, w_o, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(py_x, Y), name='cost-reduce-mean')
train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).minimize(cost, name='RMSProp-min')
predict_op = tf.argmax(py_x, 1, name='argmax')
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(py_x,1), tf.argmax(Y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), name='accuracy-reduce-mean')

# Launch the graph in a session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    #save(sess, './logs/','graph.pb', False)
    # you need to initialize all variables
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    for i in range(2):
       training_batch = zip(range(0, len(trX), batch_size),
                            range(batch_size, len(trX)+1, batch_size))
       for start, end in training_batch:
           sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end],
                                         p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})
           saver.save(sess, 'test_model1', global_step=i)

       #test_indices = np.arange(len(teX)) # Get A Test Batch
       #np.random.shuffle(test_indices)
       #test_indices = test_indices[0:test_size]
       #writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("logs/", sess.graph)
       #print(i, np.mean(np.argmax(teY[test_indices], axis=1) ==
       #                 sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X: teX[test_indices],
       #                                                 Y: teY[test_indices],
       #                                                 p_keep_conv: 1.0,
       #                                                 p_keep_hidden: 1.0})))
    save(sess,'./logs/','graph.pb', False)
    #saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
    #print tf.all_variables().
    #saver.save(sess,"checkpoint.data")
```

I can retrain the model without define the layers in the same machines

```
import tensorflow as tf
import input_data
batch_size = 128
test_size = 256

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
trX, trY, teX, teY = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels, mnist.test.images,mnist.test.labels
trX = trX.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
teX = teX.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('test_model1-1.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, 'test_model1-1')
    input_X = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_X:0')
    input_Y = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_Y:0')
    p_keep_conv = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('p_keep_conv:0')
    p_keep_hidden = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('p_keep_hidden:0')
    train_op = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('RMSProp-min')
    predict_op = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('argmax:0')

    for i in range(2):
        training_batch = zip(range(0,len(trX), batch_size),
                          range(batch_size, len(trX)+1, batch_size))
        for start, end in training_batch:
            _, result = sess.run([train_op, predict_op], feed_dict={input_X:trX[start:end],
                                          input_Y:trY[start:end],
                                          p_keep_conv:0.8,
                                          p_keep_hidden:0.5})

            print len(result)
            new_saver.save(sess, 'test_model_re', global_step=i)
```

It's all right to run, But when i change the code to be distributed version to train in the distributed machines, i failed with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_conv2_metagraph.py", line 221, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "mnist_conv2_metagraph.py", line 111, in main
    saver.restore(sess_pre, 'test_model1-1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1105, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot colocate nodes 'save/Assign_14' and 'Variable_4/RMSProp_1: Cannot merge devices with incompatible jobs: '/job:worker' and '/job:ps/task:1'
         [[Node: save/Assign_14 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_4"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:worker"](Variable_4/RMSProp_1, save/restore_slice_14)]]
Caused by op u'save/Assign_14', defined at:
  File "mnist_conv2_metagraph.py", line 221, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "mnist_conv2_metagraph.py", line 110, in main
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('test_model1-1.meta')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1431, in import_meta_graph
    return _import_meta_graph_def(read_meta_graph_file(meta_graph_or_file))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1321, in _import_meta_graph_def
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 274, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2260, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

the code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import input_data
import math
import sys
import tempfile
import time
import func_path

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_boolean("download_only", False,
                     "Only perform downloading of data; Do not proceed to "
                     "session preparation, model definition or training")
flags.DEFINE_integer("worker_index", 0,
                     "Worker task index, should be >= 0. worker_index=0 is "
                     "the master worker task the performs the variable "
                     "initialization ")
flags.DEFINE_integer("num_workers", 4,
                     "Total number of workers (must be >= 1)")
flags.DEFINE_integer("num_parameter_servers", 2,
                     "Total number of parameter servers (must be >= 1)")
flags.DEFINE_integer("replicas_to_aggregate", None,
                     "Number of replicas to aggregate before parameter update"
                     "is applied (For sync_replicas mode only; default: "
                     "num_workers)")
flags.DEFINE_integer("grpc_port", 2222,
                     "TensorFlow GRPC port")
flags.DEFINE_integer("train_steps", 200,
                     "Number of (global) training steps to perform")
flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", 100, "Training batch size")
flags.DEFINE_float("learning_rate", 0.01, "Learning rate")
flags.DEFINE_string("worker_grpc_url", "grpc://10.10.228.80:2222",
                    "Worker GRPC URL (e.g., grpc://1.2.3.4:2222, or "
                    "grpc://tf-worker0:2222)")
flags.DEFINE_boolean("sync_replicas", False,
                     "Use the sync_replicas (synchronized replicas) mode, "
                     "wherein the parameter updates from workers are aggregated "
                     "before applied to avoid stale gradients")
flags.DEFINE_string("ps_server", "",
                    "PS server lists separated by ';'")
flags.DEFINE_string("worker_server", "",
                    "Worker server lists separated by ';'")

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


PARAM_SERVER_PREFIX = "tf-ps"  # Prefix of the parameter servers' domain names
WORKER_PREFIX = "tf-worker"  # Prefix of the workers' domain names


def get_device_setter(num_parameter_servers, num_workers):
    ps_spec = []
    ps_list = FLAGS.ps_server.split(';')
    for j in range(num_parameter_servers):
        ps_spec.append(ps_list[j])

    worker_spec = []
    worker_list = FLAGS.worker_server.split(';')
    for k in range(num_workers):
        worker_spec.append(worker_list[k])
    cluster_spec = tf.train.ClusterSpec({
        "ps": ps_spec,
        "worker": worker_spec})
    return tf.train.replica_device_setter(cluster=cluster_spec)



def main(_):
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
    batch_size = 128
    #test_size = 256
    print("Worker GRPC URL: %s" % FLAGS.worker_grpc_url)
    print("Worker index = %d" % FLAGS.worker_index)
    print("Number of workers = %d" % FLAGS.num_workers)

    if FLAGS.worker_index >= FLAGS.num_workers:
        raise ValueError("Worker index %d exceeds number of workers %d ") % (FLAGS.worker_index, FLAGS.num_workers)

    if FLAGS.num_parameter_servers <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid num_parameter_servers value: %d" % FLAGS.num_parameter_servers)

    is_chief = (FLAGS.worker_index == 0)

    if FLAGS.sync_replicas:
        if FLAGS.replicas_to_aggregate is None:
            replicas_to_aggregate = FLAGS.num_workers
        else:
            replicas_to_aggregate = FLAGS.replicas_to_aggregate


    device_setter = get_device_setter(FLAGS.num_parameter_servers, FLAGS.num_workers)

    def variable_summaries(var, name):
        with tf.name_scope('summaries'):
            mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
            tf.scalar_summary('mean/' + name, mean)
            with tf.name_scope('stddev'):
                stddev = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(var-mean)))
            tf.scalar_summary('stddev/'+name, stddev)
            tf.scalar_summary('max/'+name, tf.reduce_max(var))
            tf.scalar_summary('min/'+name, tf.reduce_min)

    with tf.device(device_setter):
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
        sess_pre = tf.Session()
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('test_model1-1.meta')
        input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        for node in input_graph_def.node:
            node.device = ""
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(input_graph_def, name="")
        saver.restore(sess_pre, 'test_model1-1')
        pre_graph = sess_pre.graph

        init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        train_dir = tempfile.mktemp()
        merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
        saver = func_path.prepare()
        sv = tf.train.Supervisor(graph=pre_graph,
                                 is_chief=is_chief,
                                 logdir=train_dir,
                                 init_op=init_op,
                                 recovery_wait_secs=1,
                                 global_step=global_step)
        sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(
                allow_soft_placement=True,
                log_device_placement=True,
                device_filters=['/job:ps','/job:worker/task:%d'%FLAGS.worker_index])
        if is_chief:
            print("Worker %d: Initializing session..."% FLAGS.worker_index )
        else:
            print("Worker %d: Waiting for session to be initialized..." % FLAGS.worker_index)
        sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(FLAGS.worker_grpc_url, config=sess_config)
        #new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('test_model1-1.meta')
        #new_saver.restore(sess, 'test_model1-1')
        input_X = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_X:0')
        input_Y = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_Y:0')
        p_keep_conv = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('p_keep_conv:0')
        p_keep_hidden = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('p_keep_hidden:0')
        cost = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('cost-reduce-mean')
        train_op = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('RMSProp')
        accuracy = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('accuracy-reduce-mean')
        train_step = train_op.minimize(cost, global_step=global_step)
        if FLAGS.sync_replicas:
            train_op = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(
                    train_op,
                    replicas_to_aggregate=replicas_to_aggregate,
                    total_num_replicas=FLAGS.num_workers,
                    replica_id=FLAGS.worker_index,
                    name="mnist_sync_replicas")

        if FLAGS.sync_replicas and is_chief:
            # Initial token and chief queue runners required by the sync_replicas mode
            chief_queue_runner = train_op.get_chief_queue_runner()
            init_tokens_op = train_op.get_init_tokens_op()


        train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.summaries_dir + '/train', sess.graph)
        test_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.summaries_dir + '/test')
        print("Worker %d: Session initialization complete."%FLAGS.worker_index)
        if FLAGS.sync_replicas and is_chief:
            print("Starting chief queue runner and running init_tokens_op")
            sv.start_queue_runners(sess,[chief_queue_runner])
            sess.run(init_tokens_op)
        time_begin = time.time()
        print("Training begins @ %f" %time_begin)

        local_step = 0
        while True:
            if local_step % 100 == 0:
                batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.test.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
                batch_xs = batch_xs.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
                test_feed = {input_X: batch_xs,input_Y: batch_ys,p_keep_conv: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0}
                summary, acc = sess.run([merged, accuracy], feed_dict=test_feed)
                if is_chief:
                    test_writer.add_summary(summary, local_step)
                print('Accuracy at step %s: %s'%(local_step, acc))
            else:
                batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
                batch_xs = batch_xs.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
                train_feed = {input_X: batch_xs, input_Y: batch_ys, p_keep_conv: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0}
                # can't understand
                _, step = sess.run([train_step, global_step], feed_dict=train_feed)
                if local_step %100 ==99:
                    now = time.time()
                    print('%f: Workr %d: training step %d done (global step: %d)'%(now, FLAGS.worker_index, local_step, step))
                    if step >= FLAGS.train_steps:
                        break
                    if local_step % 100 == 1:
                        if FLAGS.worker_index == 1:
                            func_path.save(sess, saver, FLAGS.worker_index)
                        if FLAGS.worker_index == 2:
                            func_path.save(sess, saver, FLAGS.worker_index)
                        if FLAGS.worker_index == 3:
                            func_path.save(sess, saver, FLAGS.worker_index)
            local_step+=1

        time_end = time.time()
        print('Training ends @ %f' % time_end)
        training_time = time_end - time_begin
        print("Training elapsed time: %f s"% training_time)
        val_images = mnist.validation.images
        val_images = val_images.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
        val_labels = mnist.validation.labels
        val_feed = {input_X: val_images,input_Y: val_labels,p_keep_conv: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0}

        val_xent = sess.run(cost, feed_dict=val_feed)
        print("After %d training step(s), validation cross entropy = %g"%
              (FLAGS.train_steps, val_xent))
        acc =  sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=val_feed)
        print("After %d training step(s), validation acc = %g"%(FLAGS.train_steps, acc))
        if is_chief:
            print("here")
            func_path.save(sess, saver, FLAGS.worker_index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Anybody can help me with the distributed version, thanks

Comment: Try adding the option 'clear_devices=True' to the call to 'tf.train.import_meta_graph()'.

Comment: Thanks!  I see the saver.py with clear_devices, I will try it later

Comment: @PeterHawkins I change the import_meta_graph and _import_meta_graph with the clear_devices in the saver.py and add the option, but it fails by the same error. Can you push a example that how to retrain with the checkpoint model in distributed machines